# Hollow object with Boolean filling up with ocean modifier?

Tags: modeling

I honestly am having a hard time describing this error, it may just be a bug. I've included a .blend file and screenshots as a reference.

I have a ship in a bottle on a plane with an ocean modifier, the plane also has booleans, so that the ship stays hollow. This works, but on frame 14 the ship suddenly fills with the entire ocean material.

I've been experimenting with the modifiers trying to figure out what the issue is. At this point I'm a bit lost.

Here is what the image should look like:[image]

Here is what it looks like on render:[image]

I've also attached a blend. I'm completely lost, any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Blend File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zLqDeVBwMfVUwvZ593x8OzJT1_DKmFid/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The Ocean modifier simply generates a surface - it won’t fill it into a conainer like a fluid simulation would. Therefore, I suspect the problem is with the Boolean modifier. At Blender version 2.79 the Boolean modifier provides solver options of BMesh and Carve. Does changing the Solver resolve the problem?

Comment: So, I didn't change anything, but I clicked on and off all the render icons for the booleans and now it works.

Either something got left off that I didn't realize or it fixed whatever bug was occurring.

Comment: Great - glad it’s working. Please add an answer to your own question so you can mark it as ‘accepted’ for others to benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I didn't change anything, but I clicked on and off all the render icons for the booleans and now it works. Either something got left off that I didn't realize or it fixed whatever bug was occurring. – Remington Jul 18 at 19:01